# Handling Binary String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, binary, byte, react-native-camera

## The Problem

I am using a phone camera barcode scanner on React Native to scan a barcode, this library returns me a ***String*** of the RawData and what i need is a ***Byte Array*** of the data because i need to decrypt it to obtain a ***printable String***.

The problem is that it contains binary data that is not ASCII (greater than 127) so the method `charCodeAt()`  doesnt works to me because it only handles ASCII characters.

## The Question

Is there any way to convert a ***string character*** to binary data, it could be decimal or hex byte?

***Additional data:*** I am using RNCamera with GoogleVisionBarcodes.

Comment: do you have an example and wanted result?

Comment: Can you please provide your input string and the expected output to make it clear?

Comment: This is the input barcode PDF417: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSsdpiyYJaJ9XVIeE6WkNCWnviq7PAil/view?usp=sharing

And the expected output is: 
[16, 01, 32, 94, 32, 3f, a7, 20,  97, 94, 60, b0, 4a, 9e, 4f, 85, ]etc...

Comment: I am using this webpage to get expected result: https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/
Select PDF417 and upload the image that i provided.

Comment: And the string that throw me "RawData" is this: 22?§ `°J
A'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'}KòA Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñu¡AIIhNáVFÖ@ Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 ��Þ#èÐ6á9í040> Ñ3àÐ1é��0Ðòÿ²Þy´O
                                                                                               m¢+Jb_Pb¯½tW9I«Öjý@p¼¢t¥àµÍCGkOBP µBXl'{Ï¯Ò^W{ibzD{wý9O:flz'æ5éÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'0 �� Ñ3àÐ��ß��'2  £_l D±~|U
                                         etc...